# std::vector mixed data types

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I was trying to read in a list of numbers and letters into a `std::vector<char>`. As it produced errors, I tried only to read in numbers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<char> zahlen;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        zahlen.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < zahlen.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<zahlen[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This produces some strange output. What am I doing wrong? How can I store multiple types of data in a vector or another container?

EDIT:

```
cout<<(int)zahlen[i];
```

This did the job for displaying the content, but how do I identify the different types of data?

Comment: "How can I store multiple types of data in a vector or another container?" You can't directly (in a `std::vector`). What do you want to achieve (why do you want to store numbers *and* letters in the same `vector`)?

Comment: "This produces some strange output." as the elements of the `vector` are of type `char`, using `cout << zahlen[i]` outputs the numbers interpreted as characters.

Comment: What you want to do is `cout << (int)zahlen[i];`. (Or `cout << static_cast<int>(zahlen[i]);`, whatever floats your boat). Better yet, using `std::vector<int>` should solve the problem. :V

Comment: So (int)zahlen[i] did it well, but how do I identify the type of the input?

Comment: What's "strange output"?

Comment: @KerrekSB nothing a terminal can print out. There's just a blank line and an error sound.

Comment: `std::vector` is a homogeneous container. It can only hold elements of the same type. What you're looking for is a heterogeneous container. The standard C++ library doesn't offer such a container, so you'll have to use a 3rd party library for this, like Boost.Any (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html)

Comment: Using a `std::vector` as a buffer... it must be for some bad programming contest.

Comment: Can you clarify if what you meant by "numbers"? Did you actually only mean the decimal digits, or did you mean arbitrary integer values?

Comment: @Magnus: Why is that "strange"? That's exactly what I'd expect my terminal to do with those control characters, so I'd find that "reassuringly expected".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `for` loop, I will assume when you said "numbers", you actually meant "decimal digits".

You can use `std::vector<char>` to store decimal digits and letters, but they are all going to be represented as `char`. You can account for that by using the character encoding of your system to store the decimal digits. One simple way:

```
    vector<char> zahlen;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        zahlen.push_back('0' + i);
    }
```

If instead of "decimal digits" you really mean arbitrary numbers, then you need something more complicated than a `char` for your `vector`. As suggested in the comments, [`Boost.Any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html) is a possibility.

Comment: `Boost.Any` is comprehensive, but it is not that difficult to put together something simpler on your own. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/IonCML) for an example.

Comment: Or just use a tuple...

Comment: @JimR: While a `tuple<>` can hold heterogeneous data, it is a static type.